SQL Server not using filtered index for a query
I created this index:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Speedup_04] 
ON [Sessions] ([ServerName] ASC, [SessionId] ASC, [CreatedTime] ASC)
WHERE ([UniqueSessionId] IS NULL)


But the query:
 UPDATE [Sessions]  
 SET UniqueSessionId = COALESCE(ServerName, '') + '-' + SessionId + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CAST(CreatedTime AS DATE), 120)
 WHERE UniqueSessionId IS NULL 

is not using that index. I did an index rebuild and a statistics update.
SQL Server is still doing a full scan on other index with seek on columns ServerName, SessionId and CreatedTime and then doing filter after doing scan on so many rows.

Also currently there is no row in table with UniqueSessionId null. So it should have used that filtered index.
I also cleared query cache.


Not sure if 0 rows were fetched doing scan, why still doing keylookup on servername..
Even removing coalesce and rebuild, still not using filtered index
Changed it to concat, still the same 
Not sure how cardinality affected..

This looks to be the same symptoms as this bug which has not yet been fixed. A workaround is to add UniqueSessionId as an included or key column. The other key columns are not useful for the update query performance.

How many rows in the table and how many meet the criteria UniqueSessionId IS NULL? Looks like 11 million in the table and (from size of the execution plan arrows) very few where  UniqueSessionId IS NULL?

@MartinSmith : 0 rows

It can do it with a hint and costs the plan as much less https://i.sstatic.net/2TSgJpM6.png - if UniqueSessionId is added as an included column it doesn't need the hint - but even without that it only estimates one lookup is needed anyway and estimated plan cost is lower than the one it chooses

Two general comments here.  First, the three columns in your index do not even appear in the WHERE clause of the update query.  Only the UniqueSessionId does appear in the WHERE clause, but it is not part of the index.  A simple index which might get used would just include the UniqueSessionId column alone.
But second, such an index might not even be used by SQL Server, assuming there were a fairly even division of records with null and non null UniqueSessionId.  In that case, it might be faster to just do the update with a full table scan.

The images in your question show the table has 10,86,977 rows.
You confirm that currently 0 of them match the [UniqueSessionId] IS NULL predicate.
To set up something similar I used
CREATE TABLE [Sessions]
(
RowId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
ServerName varchar(50),
[SessionId] int, 
[CreatedTime] datetime,
[UniqueSessionId] varchar(100) null
)

insert [Sessions]
SELECT 'foo',1,getdate(),'foo'
FROM generate_series(1, 10986977)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Speedup_04] 
ON [Sessions] ([ServerName] ASC, [SessionId] ASC, [CreatedTime] ASC)
WHERE ([UniqueSessionId] IS NULL)

The execution plan I get for the UPDATE below has an estimated cost of 40.7141 and does a full table scan
 UPDATE [Sessions]  
 SET UniqueSessionId = COALESCE(ServerName, '') + '-' + SessionId + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CAST(CreatedTime AS DATE), 120)
 WHERE UniqueSessionId IS NULL 


This is of course annoying when it could just scan IDX_Speedup_04 and get the very small set of clustered index keys that match the UniqueSessionId IS NULL predicate (in this case zero) and then drive the UPDATE from those.
An explicit index hint does give this plan (with a plan cost of 0.0165721)
 UPDATE [Sessions]
  SET UniqueSessionId = COALESCE(ServerName, '') + '-' + SessionId + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CAST(CreatedTime AS DATE), 120)
  from [Sessions] with(index = IDX_Speedup_04)
 WHERE UniqueSessionId IS NULL 


The key lookup is also annoying and is there for the reasons given in the bug linked by Dan but even with the key lookup the plan is still costed at less than 1/2000th of the cost of the plan it eventually chooses.
If the index is changed to
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Speedup_05] 
ON [Sessions] ([ServerName] ASC, [SessionId] ASC, [CreatedTime] ASC) INCLUDE ([UniqueSessionId])
WHERE ([UniqueSessionId] IS NULL)

It now does choose the desired plan naturally without any hints and this time the plan cost is 0.0132844

I presume this is just some limitation that it doesn't consider the second plan naturally (without hints) as it does cost it much cheaper when forced to consider it.

create index IDX_CMS_Sessions_Speedup_04 on bar.cms.sessions(UniqueSessionId) include  ( ServerName, SessionId, CreatedTime)
  where  UniqueSessionId IS NULL

The above index worked.
But not sure why doing spool. 0 rows returned.


You are searching by UniqueSessionId.
But that column is not in the index.
The index you created only contains ServerName, SessionId and CreatedTime.
The WHERE ([UniqueSessionId] IS NULL) is just a criteria.
You should search the other columns or include UniqueSessionId in the index, like:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Speedup_04] ON [Sessions]
(
    [ServerName] ASC,
    [SessionId] ASC,
    [CreatedTime] ASC,
    [UniqueSessionId]
)

If you are using only that column in the search, create another index exclusive for it:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Speedup_04B] ON [Sessions]
(
    [UniqueSessionId]
)

That because the column, to have effect when used alone, should be the first column in the index.
